# How to use a variable in azure RESTAPI

Tags: azure, powershell, api, rest

I am trying to List all resource groups using azure RestAPI in my PowerShell variable and use the part of it in another Azure API to list the virtual machines.

```
$RG_List = Invoke-RestMethod 'https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/my_subscription_id/resourcegroups?api-version=2021-04-01' -Method 'GET' -Headers $headers


$RG_VM = Invoke-RestMethod "https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/my_subscription_id/resourceGroups/$RG_List.value.name[0]/providers/Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines?api-version=2022-11-01" -Method 'GET' -Headers $headers
```

But it is not giving me right result and  I am getting this error

```
Invoke-RestMethod : {"error":{"code":"ResourceGroupNotFound","message":"Resource group '@{value=System.Object[]}.value.name[0]' could not be found."}}
At C:\Users\intre\Downloads\Untitled2.ps1:11 char:10
+ $RG_VM = Invoke-RestMethod "https://management.azure.com/subscription ...
+          ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (System.Net.HttpWebRequest:HttpWebRequest) [Invoke-RestMethod], WebException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : WebCmdletWebResponseException,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.InvokeRestMethodCommand
```

However If I use the exact name of the resource group in the API, I am getting the desired result.How will I be able to use a variable in the Get request of this URL?

Comment: Use `$( )` to interpolate it: `.../resourceGroups/$($RG_List.value.name[0])/providers...`

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @Santiago Squarzon for leading into right direction.

*I have reproduced the issue by following the below steps:*

1. Initialized Resource groups:

```
$RG_List = "pravutestrg1", "pravutestrg2"
```

2. Initialized Headers:

```
$headers=@{"Authorization"="Bearer "+ $token}
```

3. Executing API using command:

```
$RG_VM = Invoke-RestMethod "https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/<subscription-id>/resourceGroups/$($RG_List[0])/providers/Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines?api-version=2022-11-01" -Method 'GET' -Headers $headers
```

**Result:**

[image]

**References:**

Refer to [MSDOC](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_arrays?view=powershell-7.3#accessing-and-using-array-elements), for more details about arrays in powershell: